# Could not find or load main class edu.towson.cosc336.bcornewll.Lab1

Tags: java, cmd, command-prompt

Im writing a program that is supposed to be simple, review stuff, but its the first time Ive used the cmd prompt and any file writing stuff, in java. Whenever I run the file, in cmd prompt, i am met with this error. 
[this error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rkboy.png)

I am supposed to take the input file, scan the contents then compose a list of sums, averages etc. but the cmd prompt cannot load my main method! Any help is extremely appreciated.

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws FileNotFoundException {
    if(args.length < 1) {
        System.out.print("Need param");
    }else{
        File inFile = new File(args[0]);
        File outFile = new File(args[1]);
        Scanner console = new Scanner(inFile);
        PrintWriter writer = new PrintWriter(outFile);


        int size = console.nextInt();
        int data[] = new int[size];
        int sum=0;
        double avg = 1;
        int min = 999999;
        int max = -999999;

        for (String a : args) {
            System.out.println(a);}
        for(int i = 0; i < size; i++) {
            data[i] = console.nextInt();
            sum = sum + data[i];
            avg = sum / size;

            if (data[i] < min)
                data[i] = min;
            if (data[i] > max)
                data[i] = max;
        }
        PrintWriter write = new PrintWriter("output.txt");

        write.println("Sum; " + sum);
        write.println("Avg: " + avg);
        write.println("Min: " + min);
        write.println("Max: " + max);
        writer.close();
        }

    }

}
```

I havent been able to run through the program to check for logic errors becuase i havent even managed to get cmd prompt to load the main method yet. What am i doing wrong?

Comment: You are missing class in java file

Comment: Don't post pictures of text here, or links to them. Post the text.

Answer (score 1):

You are not following the structure of java program. Class is missing from your file. 
You should follow the java program structure.

Sample is given below. ClassName and file name should match.

```
public class ClassName
{
    public static void main(String args[])
    {
        //Code
    }
}
```